# How to find the smallest threshold from one list to fit another list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists of marks for the same set of students. For example:

```
A = [22, 2, 88, 3, 93, 84]
B = [66, 0, 6, 33, 99, 45]
```

If I accept only students above a threshold according to list A then I can look up their marks in list B. For example, if I only accept students with at least a mark of 80 from list A then their marks in list B are [6, 99, 45].

I would like to compute the smallest threshold for A which gives at least 90% of students in the derived set in B getting at least 50. In this example the threshold will have to be 93 which gives the list [99] for B.

Another example:

```
A = [3, 36, 66, 88, 99, 52, 55, 42, 10, 70]
B = [5, 30, 60, 80, 80, 60, 45, 45, 15, 60]
```

In this case we have to set the threshold to 66 which then gives 100% of [60, 80, 80, 60] getting at least 50.

Comment: Your question as it stands is a bit confusing, I didn't downvote by the way

Comment: @DaniMesejo How can I help clarify it?

Comment: What does this means: How to find the smallest threshold from one list to fit another list

Comment: maybe just try to go through the list A, look if it passes the threshold and if it does, get the index (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) and take the element with that index from list B

Comment: @DaniMesejo I added a paragraph which I hope makes it clearer.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: @sputnick567 Not a good idea, you can't reliably get the index of a value if it appears more than once in a list. That here would be a job for `zip`.

Comment: @TimurShtatland I don't know how to do it so I don't have code yet.

Comment: @graffe "A which gives at least 90% of students in the derived set in B getting over 50%. " Can you elaborate what is the `50%` about? Do you want the threshold to be such that you get a minimum of `50%` students from B? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: @TheMyth The % wasn't helpful. It just means their score in list B is at least 50.

Comment: @graffe then can you provide some more example cases that are on the lines of the paragraph you wrote.

Comment: @TheMyth I I want at least 90% of the students to get at least 50 from the derived list from B.

Comment: @TheMyth Another example added

Comment: @graffe what do you mean by "100% of [60, 80, 80, 60]. Do your values in B need to be greater than 50, or what?

Comment: @TheMyth  Yes. 100% of  [60, 80, 80, 60] are at least 50. Remember I need at least 90% of them to be.

Comment: @graffe why is your output `[60, 80, 80, 60]` and not `[60, 80, 80, 60, 60]`. The last 60 comes from the last index of A. Give it a look, it's more than `66`.

Comment: @TheMyth If I set a threshold in A of 66 then within A the values at least 66 are 66, 88, 99,  70. That's only four numbers.  They correspond to [60, 80, 80, 60]  in B. I can't set a smaller threshold because 55 in A gets mapped to 45 in B.

Comment: @graffe alright, check if my answer helps. It's an improved version of Pranav.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an *O(nlogn + m)* approach (due to sorting) where *n* is the length of `A` and *m* is the length of `B`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import accumulate


def find_threshold(lst_a, lst_b):
    # find the order of the indices of lst_a according to the marks
    indices, values = zip(*sorted(enumerate(lst_a), key=itemgetter(1)))

    # find the cumulative sum of the elements of lst_b above 50 sorted by indices
    cumulative = list(accumulate(int(lst_b[j] > 50) for j in indices))

    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        # find the index where the elements above 50 is greater than 90%
        if cumulative[-1] - cumulative[i - 1] > 0.9 * (len(values) - i):
            return value

    return None


print(find_threshold([22, 2, 88, 3, 93, 84], [66, 0, 6, 33, 99, 45]))
print(find_threshold([3, 36, 66, 88, 99, 52, 55, 42, 10, 70], [5, 30, 60, 80, 80, 60, 45, 45, 15, 60]))
```

**Output**

```
93
66
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define a function that will tell you if 90% of students in a set scored more than 50:

```
def setb_90pc_pass(b):
    return sum(score >= 50 for score in b) >= len(b) * 0.9
```

Next, loop over scores in `a` in ascending order, setting each of them as the threshold. Filter out your lists according that threshold, and check if they fulfill your condition:

```
for threshold in sorted(A):
    filtered_a, filtered_b = [], []
    for ai, bi in zip(A, B):
        if ai >= threshold:
            filtered_a.append(ai)
            filtered_b.append(bi)
    if setb_90pc_pass(filtered_b):
        break

print(threshold)
```

Comment: Can this be done by binary search?

Comment: This fails with the sample input `A = [3, 36, 66, 88, 99, 52, 55, 42, 10, 70]
B = [5, 30, 60, 80, 80, 60, 45, 45, 15, 60]`. It returns thres to be 99, when 66 is expected.

Comment: @TheMyth I misunderstood OP's requirement so my code was returning the _largest_ threshold. Iterating in ascending order instead of descending order fixes the issue. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @graffe binary search needs that the items are sorted. In this case, the Y value (percentage of `filtered_b` that scored above 50%) is not guaranteed to be monotonically increasing or decreasing. For example in your first set of example inputs, this percentage varies as `[33.333, 40, 50, 33.333, 50, 100]` for thresholds of `[2, 3, 22, 84, 88, 93]`, so I don't think you can use binary search

Comment: @PranavHosangadi considering your original answer is working, my answer isn't needed. Let's get rid of that :)